# Does this NPC's curse from the Curse of Strahd published adventure remain active even after the NPC dies?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, duration, curse-of-strahd, curses

The NPC [Ezmerelda d'Avenir](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/17364-ezmerelda-davenir) from *Curse of Strahd* (p. 230) has this action (emphasis mine):

> ***Curse (Recharges after a Long Rest).*** Ezmerelda targets one creature that she can see within 30 feet of her. The target must succeed on a DC 14 Wisdom saving throw or be cursed. While cursed, the target has vulnerability to one type of damage of Ezmerelda’s choice. **The curse lasts until ended with a *greater restoration* spell, a *remove curse* spell, or similar magic. When the curse ends, Ezmerelda takes 3d6 psychic damage.**

In my game, Ezmerelda was dominated and used this curse on a PC to give them fire vulnerability. Shortly after that, she died.

As I would rule it, the curse stays until it is dispelled, even though she is dead and can't take the 3d6 psychic damage. Is my ruling correct, according to RAW/RAI?

P.S.: The party has access to *remove curse*, so one PC having fire vulnerability for a session or two is not a huge issue.

Comment: There should be a duplicate for this. A spell/effect that lists multiple things has *as much as possible of it* happening. I can't find the duplicate that explains it right now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### "The curse lasts until ended with a *greater restoration* spell, a *remove curse* spell, or similar magic"

The ability does not require that Ezmerelda be alive for the curse to work. This also is not a concentration effect that requires her to concentrate to sustain it. The curse states the conditions under which it will end:

- *Greater Restoration* gets cast on the target
- *Remove Curse* gets cast on the target
- A similar spell gets cast on the target

This list of conditions does not include the death of Ezmerelda, so her death does not affect an active curse.

*When the curse ends, Ezmerelda takes 3d6 psychic damage* is a result of the curse ending, not a condition. If she is dead, this won't happen (as corpses are objects, and objects are typically immune to psychic damage).